# How to pass command line arguments to compiled php

Tags: php, command

i have compiled a script unsing Phalanger to exe, now i would like to pass commnad line arguments to it... like this: myapp.exe argument1

Comment: did you try ... within the script is should be accessible as `$argv[1]`;

Comment: RTLM? http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: I don't know if this might be useful to you. I had to write a command line arguments parser for work a while back. It's called [ParParse](https://github.com/jordanhalterman/ParParse) (crappy name, I know). Haven't used it in a while, but I did use it for handling command line PHP scripts for a while and it worked well. It supports a variety of common command line argument types.